# Show that $C_0([0,\infty))$ is complete.

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $C_b([0,\infty))$ be the space of bounded continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$. On $C_b([0,\infty))$ we define a norm by $\|f\|_\infty = \sup\{|f(x)| : x\in [0,\infty)\}$. Furthermore, define 
\begin{equation}
C_0([0,\infty)) = \{f \in C_b([0,\infty)):\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f(x) = 0\}
\end{equation}

**Exercise:** Show that $C_0([0,\infty)), \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is complete.
Hint: you can use that $(C_b([0,\infty)),\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is a complete space.

I know that:

- If $(C_b([0,\infty)),\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is a complete space, $C_0([0,\infty)), \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is complete if $C_0([0,\infty))$ is closed in $C_b([0,\infty))$.
- $C_0([0,\infty))$ is closed $\Leftrightarrow$ $B_\epsilon(x) \cap C_0([0,\infty)) \neq \emptyset$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, then $x\in C_0([0,\infty))$.

*What I think I should do:*

Pick $x\in C_b([0,\infty))$ such that $B_\epsilon(x)\cap C_0([0,\infty)) \neq \emptyset$ for every $\epsilon >0$. Then; show that $x\in C_0([0,\infty))$ as well.

**Question:** How do I show that $(C_0([0,\infty)), \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is complete by using my approach and showing that $x\in C_0([0,\infty))$ as well?

Comment: This was asked very recently.

Comment: You can prove that every sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $C_0([0,+\infty))$ that converges to some $x \in C_b([0,+\infty))$, should also have $x \in C_b([0,+\infty))$. This implies that $C_0([0,+\infty))$ is closed in $C_b([0,+\infty))$ and thus complete.

Comment: If you don't notice the difference between $||a||$ and $\|a\|,$ maybe you'll notice the difference between $||a|| ||b||$ and $\|a\|\|b\|.$ I edited accordingly, and also changed $sup$ to $\sup. \qquad$

Comment: @copper.hat Would this edit make the question eligible again? Thanks for pointing out that it's a duplicate.

Comment: @titusAdam: I think it is still essentially the same question.